# Rendering large database record set as JSON in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb, mongoid

Is there a way to present a large record set in JSON format without consuming large amount of memory? For example I have the following query:

```
...
records = Records.where(query)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json  { render :json => records.to_json }
end
```

There are times that records will contain thousands of entries and JSON is strictly used for getting the data without using pagination and such data must fit inside the memory for it to be returned. A `Record` entry will also contain a lot of fields (I am using MongoDB/Mongoid) and it is necessary to include such fields.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always a bad idea to return every resource in a database.

You can respond with limited set of results and provide total number of records.

For example:

```
{
  total: 503
  records: [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 }
  ]
}
```

And add possibility to use `limit` and `offset` parameters to iterate through all pages.

There is chapter named **Pagination and partial response** in free e-book [Web API Design](http://pages.apigee.com/web-api-design-ebook.html) describes it.

I would recommend you to read that book. It contains only 30 pages.

**upd**:
In your case you are able to paginate results using `limit` and `skip` mongoid's methods.

```
records = Records.where(query).limit(params[:limit]).skip(params[:offset])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json  { render :json => { total: records.count, records: records }.to_json }
end
```

Comment: Um, I cannot use `limit` and `offset` since I am returning the data in JSON format not in paginated form

Comment: why not? I've added mongoid explanation

Comment: I mean, the requirement is that all matching records will have to be presented in plain JSON format.

Comment: OK, I tried to just reduce the fields that I am returning. But I am just confused about the eager/lazy loading of Mongoid. If one of the records references a another model with many documents, are these also being loaded into the memory too?